# Checkout API Failing Using Card Vault

Tags: rest, paypal, vault

We are getting below exception for checkout order API if we using Vault. Same card is working fine if we do payment from User Interface paypal plugin. I have tried to get support from pay pal merchant support team but not received any response yet. Also tried different requests with multiple cards but issue persists. Also went through developer doc but not get any useful information yet.

URL : https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders

Request :

```
{
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "1.00",
                "breakdown": {
                "item_total": {  
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": "1.00"
                }
                }
            },
            "items":[
            {
               "name":"bottle",
               "unit_amount":{
                  "currency_code":"USD",
                  "value":"1.00"
               },
               "quantity":1
            }
         ]
        }
    ],
   "application_context":{
      "brand_name":"MY STORE",
      "shipping_preference":"NO_SHIPPING"
   },
   "payer":{
      "email_address":"asddsafdasffads@as.es",
      "address":{
         "address_line_1":"asdf",
         "address_line_2":"dsaf",
         "admin_area_2":"Madrid",
         "admin_area_1":"Madrid",
         "postal_code":"28045",
         "country_code":"ES"
      },
      "name":{
         "given_name":"Vinxxx",
         "surname":"Kamtxxxxx"
      }
   },
    "payment_source": {
        "card": {
            "vault_id": "bxaqaknk"
        }
    }
}
```

Response :

```
{
    "name": "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
    "details": [
        {
            "issue": "PAYMENT_DENIED",
            "description": "PAYMENT_DENIED"
        }
    ],
    "message": "The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
    "debug_id": "72cb109aaf274",
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PAYMENT_DENIED",
            "rel": "information_link",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The payment was denied by PayPal. The owner of the card can contact PayPal for support, it is not a technical issue.